# Opening a website when a button on the form is clicked

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating a windows application using C#, where in a button on the GUI when clicked, should open a website.

The web browser will be taken care of by the default settings.

I am curious as to how to do that?

Comment: Do you want to render the webpage inside your `winform` or opening in a browser would do?

Comment: Both would do! However, I would prefer rendering the webpage in the Winform.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the point is to open a website in your application, you will have to use WebBrowser control. 
Put WebBrowser control on your form, and add this code to the button which is responsible for opening the site:

```
webBrowser1.Navigate("www.google.com");
```

Comment: by "Put WebBrowser control on your form", do you mean to put `using WebBrowser;` at the top ?

Comment: I mean that you should find the WebBrowser control in the designer view and drag & drop it on your application panel.

Comment: I don't see it anywhere. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @Ooker you can't see it probably because you're using dotnet core, and apparently it is only available till dotnet framework 4.x

Answer (score 19):

This will open the specified link in the default web browser:

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: I get `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified.'`. Do you know why is that?

Comment: That suggests that the default handler for `html` files isn't set correctly. What happens when you try and open a web page from Windows Explorer?

Comment: it opens Google fine in my default browser when I'm not opening it

Answer (score 2):

In Windows8 the Process class has been dropped so I've used the `Launcher` class:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("http://www.google.com"));
```

You'll also need to set the method to async ( for example `private async void myMethod(object params)` )

Answer (score 1):

Use `WebBrowser` class. The below [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) has the code explained. Hope it helps.

Comment: This opens the website in `Winform` itself.